# Custom checkbox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

Is there a way to have a checkbox with a specific colour for the border when it's unchecked and then when it's checked to have a different colour for the border and a black tick without using images?

Thanks!

Comment: Set Image in background according to click state

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to do it without images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...used the Materialcheckbox

MaterialCheckBox.java

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class MaterialCheckBox extends View {

    private Paint paintBlue;
    private Paint paintWithe;
    private Paint paintCenter;

    private int borderColor = Color.GRAY;
    private int backgroundColor = Color.BLUE;
    private int doneShapeColor = Color.WHITE;

    private int baseWidth;
    private int borderWidth;
    private int width, height;

    private float[] points = new float[8];

    private int DURATION = 200;
    private boolean checked;
    private float correctProgress;

    private boolean drawRecting;
    private boolean isAnim;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;

    private float padding;


    public MaterialCheckBox(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    }

    public MaterialCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MaterialCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MaterialCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    /**
     * init
     *
     * @param context
     */
    private void init(Context context) {

    backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray_app);
    borderColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray_app);
    borderWidth = baseWidth = dp2px(2);

    paintBlue = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintBlue.setColor(borderColor);
    paintBlue.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);

    paintWithe = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintWithe.setColor(doneShapeColor);
    paintWithe.setStrokeWidth(dp2px(2));

    paintCenter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintCenter.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    paintCenter.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        setChecked(!isChecked());
        }
    });
    drawRecting = true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    height = width = Math.max(w, h);

    points[0] = 101 / 378f * width;
    points[1] = 0.5f * width;

    points[2] = 163 / 378f * width;
    points[3] = 251 / 378f * width;

    points[4] = 149 / 378f * width;
    points[5] = 250 / 378f * width;

    points[6] = 278 / 378f * width;
    points[7] = 122 / 378f * width;

    padding = 57 / 378f * width;

    }

    /**
     * draw checkbox
     *
     * @param canvas
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    RectF rect = new RectF(padding, padding, width - padding, height - padding);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, baseWidth, baseWidth, paintBlue);
    if (drawRecting) {
        canvas.drawRect(padding + borderWidth, padding + borderWidth, width - padding - borderWidth, height - padding - borderWidth, paintCenter);
    } else {
        //画对号
        if (correctProgress > 0) {
        if (correctProgress < 1 / 3f) {
            float x = points[0] + (points[2] - points[0]) * correctProgress;
            float y = points[1] + (points[3] - points[1]) * correctProgress;
            canvas.drawLine(points[0], points[1], x, y, paintWithe);
        } else {
            float x = points[4] + (points[6] - points[4]) * correctProgress;
            float y = points[5] + (points[7] - points[5]) * correctProgress;
            canvas.drawLine(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], paintWithe);
            canvas.drawLine(points[4], points[5], x, y, paintWithe);
        }
        }
    }
    }


    public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setDoneShapeColor(int doneShapeColor) {
    this.doneShapeColor = doneShapeColor;
    paintWithe.setColor(doneShapeColor);
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int baseWidth) {
    this.baseWidth = baseWidth;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
    if (checked) {
        showRect();
    } else {
        hideCorrect();
    }
    }

    private void hideRect() {
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    drawRecting = true;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(DURATION);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float p = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        float c = 1f - p;
        borderWidth = (int) (baseWidth + c * (width - baseWidth));
        paintBlue.setColor(evaluate(c, borderColor, backgroundColor));
        invalidate();
        if (p >= 1) {
            isAnim = false;
            if (listener != null) {
            checked = false;
            listener.onCheckedChanged(MaterialCheckBox.this, checked);
            }
        }
        }
    });
    va.start();
    }

    private void showRect() {
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    drawRecting = true;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(DURATION);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float p = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        borderWidth = (int) (10 + p * (width - 10));
        paintBlue.setColor(evaluate(p, borderColor, backgroundColor));
        invalidate();
        if (p >= 1) {
            isAnim = false;
            drawRecting = false;
            showCorrect();
        }
        }
    });
    va.start();
    }

    private void showCorrect() {
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    correctProgress = 0;
    drawRecting = false;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(DURATION);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        correctProgress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        invalidate();
        if (correctProgress >= 1) {
            isAnim = false;
            if (listener != null) {
            checked = true;
            listener.onCheckedChanged(MaterialCheckBox.this, checked);
            }
        }
        }
    });
    va.start();
    }

    private void hideCorrect() {
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    correctProgress = 1;
    drawRecting = false;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(DURATION);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float p = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        correctProgress = 1f - p;
        invalidate();
        if (p >= 1) {
            isAnim = false;
            hideRect();
        }
        }
    });
    va.start();
    }

    public void setOnCheckedChangedListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    }

    interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean isChecked);
    }

    private int evaluate(float fraction, int startValue, int endValue) {
    int startInt = startValue;
    int startA = (startInt >> 24) & 0xff;
    int startR = (startInt >> 16) & 0xff;
    int startG = (startInt >> 8) & 0xff;
    int startB = startInt & 0xff;

    int endInt = endValue;
    int endA = (endInt >> 24) & 0xff;
    int endR = (endInt >> 16) & 0xff;
    int endG = (endInt >> 8) & 0xff;
    int endB = endInt & 0xff;
    return ((startA + (int) (fraction * (endA - startA))) << 24)
        | ((startR + (int) (fraction * (endR - startR))) << 16)
        | ((startG + (int) (fraction * (endG - startG))) << 8)
        | ((startB + (int) (fraction * (endB - startB))));
    }

    public int dp2px(float value) {
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    return (int) (value * (scale / 160) + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Xml

```
  <.MaterialCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_remember"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"

            />
```

Code

```
 MaterialCheckBox checkbox=(MaterialCheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);



  checkbox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new MaterialCheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    });
```

or try this https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#checkbox